# Stop insert of first row from CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Im currently importing from a CSV and i cant seem to figure out how to stop the insert of the first row.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {
//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r");     
//loop through the csv file and insert into database 

do { 
    if ($data[0]) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (id,type) VALUES 
        (
        '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
        '".addslashes($data[1])."'
        )");
        } 
} 
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,",",'"'));

echo "Done";
}
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What do you mean "stop the insert of the first row?"

Comment: Skip the first iteration by calling `fgetcsv()` one time before the loop.

Comment: on a side note, look into using [PDO](http://us3.php.net/pdo). `addslashes` is not an acceptable way to protect yourself from user input.

Answer (score 3):

If all you are trying to do is skip the first then drop the `do` and turn your loop into a regular `while` and make sure to call `fgetcsv()` once before the loop.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {
    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");     
    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 

    //Get some data first, and do nothing with it.
    $data = fgetcsv($handle,0,",",'"');

    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,",",'"')) { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (id,type) VALUES 
            (
            '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
            '".addslashes($data[1])."'
            )");
        } 
    } 

    echo "Done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before looping call `fgetcsv` once -

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {
    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle); // this calls the first row     
    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
```

Comment: Doing it this way though the OP would have issues with data from the first row getting executed in the `do` block.  The data would need to be dropped first so `if($data[0])` wouldn't pan out to `true`.